# Ajax on keyup OR paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing an Ajax request on keyup or paste. The problem is that when users use Control-V to paste, two ajax requests occur- one for paste, one for keyup.

```
$("#my-form").bind('keyup paste', function(e) {...}
```

What's a good way to bind on either keyup OR paste?

Comment: Since you're getting the `keyup` event firing when your user pastes, why do you need to bind `paste` separately?

Comment: Ideally you could store the contents, then check if they have changed each time the events fire, that way it will only run once. You can bind both (or more) events and even if two fire in a row only the first will see a change and run.

Comment: @TheZ Ended up doing that, works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` to delay the event, so it only triggers once.

```
$("#my-form").bind('keyup paste', function(e) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){
        // your code
    }, 200));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4b7y5/